# How to I parse JSON list of dictionaries in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I'm new to javascript and need to iterate through a JSON list of dictionaries to create an list for each key.

Here's my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "Color Correction",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "60"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "Conform",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "70"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 2",
        "Job": "Scanning",
        "Status": "Complete",
        "Completion": "100"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 12, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "QC only",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "50"
    }
]
```

I'm using this function to read in JSON:

```
$.getJSON('cgi-bin/fakedata.txt', function(main)
```

I want to be able to access `main['Date'] = ['August 12, 2015','August 14, 2015']`

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a runnable node program.  It looked like to me  you were trying to get the dates into a separate array.  So you could access them like dates[0].

```
#!/usr/bin/node

json = [
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "Color Correction",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "60"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "Conform",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "70"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 2",
        "Job": "Scanning",
        "Status": "Complete",
        "Completion": "100"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 12, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "QC only",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "50"
    }
];


function getDates(main) {
    dates = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < main.length; i++ ) {
        dates.push(main[i].Date);
    }
    return dates;
};

dates = getDates(json);
console.log(dates);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is just what I needed to get started.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 var x = JSON.stringify(json,["date"]);
```

You can then make it a JSON.

Comment: your array would be emtpy.

Comment: I'm assuming that json binds to his json data.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fieldValues(main, field) {
  var res = {};
  for(item of main) {
    res[item[field]] = 0;
  }
  return Object.keys(res);
}

var main = [
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "Color Correction",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "60"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "Conform",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "70"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 14, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 2",
        "Job": "Scanning",
        "Status": "Complete",
        "Completion": "100"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Aug. 12, 2015",
        "Reel": "Reel 1",
        "Job": "QC only",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Completion": "50"
    }
];

console.log(fieldValues(main, "Date"));
```